# MVC how to detect no URL parameters passed

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a controller action with many parameters. I want to return a different view if no parameters are passed. I want one line of code to detect this instead of checking each and every parameter to determine nothing was passed.

```
public ActionResult Index(SearchViewModel model)
{
    // doesn't work
    if (model.Equals(new SearchViewModel())) return View("differentview", model);
```

Or should I go about a different design approach? I have a Search controller and a SearchResults controller, I'm combining them into the same controller that will just return a different view based on what's passed to it. Should I go about doing it a different way? How are all the big boy websites out there doing it?

Comment: `if(model == null)`?

Comment: model is never null

Comment: Your `SearchViewModel` need to implement `IComparerT>` (or IComparable<T>`)

Comment: Provide an example of the SearchViewModel

Answer (score -1):

if 
(
 model == null || model.ToString() == "" ||
  model.GetType().GetProperties().Any(x => AnyNull(x.GetValue(model)))
)
{
.......
}

Comment: model is never null, and ToString always returns just the class name of the model. i doubt the lambda thing will work because the model contains List of strings intialized to new List

Comment: There's no such thing as AnyNull

Comment: So I changed my model so that the List of strings is not auto initialized to an empty collection, and the following code works: `if (!model.GetType().GetProperties().Any(x => x.GetValue(model) != null))`

Answer (score -1):

Create properties in your model, and set them to [REQUIRED] with data annotations.

```
public class SearchModel{
[Required,AllowHTml]
public string SearchTerms {get;set;}
}
```

In the controller check to see if the Model's State is valid:

```
  if(!ModelState.IsValid)return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
```